# Invalid shape (4, 460, 513) for image data

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am using `read_image` to read the image.

```
from torchvision.io import read_image
image = read_image("/content/train/000001-11.jpg")
```

Now, when I try to find the shape of the image, I get $(4, 460, 513)$ as the image shape.

But, when I use opencv to read the image, I get $(460, 513, 3)$ as the image shape.

```
img=cv2.imread("/content/train/000001-11.jpg")
```

Could anyone explain to me why this happens? Why are there 4 channels instead of three?

I tried to print the 4 channels for a particular case of the former case. I found the last channel has the value 255 for all cells.
I need to plot the image in both the cases.I am unable to plot in the case of `read_image`.
How to plot in case of `read_image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_image` from `torchvision.io` by default will read the image using reading mode `ImageReadMode.UNCHANGED`, meaning that it will read the image as it stored on disk ([see the documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/io.html#torchvision.io.read_image)). In this case, that means you will get an image with four channels: (R, G, B, A), with A being the alpha channel. `imread`, however, by default uses the flag `cv.IMREAD_COLOR` to read in the image ([see the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)), meaning that you will only get three channels: (R, G, B). The difference in the number of channels is simply caused by how the images are read. Depending on what you want you can change the default flag in `read_iamge`.

There are several ways to plot an image with four channels, using `matplotlib` is one of them. The `imshow` function of `matplotlib` allows you to plot RGBA images as per [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

Comment: Thankyou that helped.